# SharePoint Content migration from SP2013 to SP2019 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-migration, migration

I have a query regarding the migration of **SP2013 to SP2019 on-premise.**
I have gone through the Microsoft document and understood that we can migrate SP from SP2013->SP2016->SP2019.

I have doubts on content migration.

But , how the content will be moved to new environment?
Even if we do database attach method, whether the Site Collections, sites, other custom solutions will be available in new SP2019?

So is it necessary to use a 3rd party tool like **ShareGate** and if we are using it, at what stage we need to start using it?
Is it after the new SP2019 farm setup and database attach is completed?

**Note*: This is highly customised SharePoint.*

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the content database upgrade method will work and is probably the recommended approach unless you want to change the structure of your content. The content will move to the new environment when you perform the content database upgrade and when it gets attached to the new farm. The only shame about this process is that you need to upgrade it via SharePoint 2016 and then upgrade the database again with SharePoint 2019 to get it up to date. You will still need to all the usual configuration to setup your new farm.

If you have any custom features, then you will need to ensure they can be deployed to SharePoint 2019 or redevelop them if they don't work in that platform.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If there are lots of customizations like custom master pages, layouts, templates, then will this (database attach) method is recommended? Also, any comments on ShareGate?

Comment: It really depends whether you want to migrate your sites from classic to modern SharePoint sites. If you're using publishing sites, then those aren't supported by modern anyway so you would need to either continue using classic for those or migrate them in to a modern site using something like ShareGate.